# Blender game engine camera

Tags: game-engine, camera

My problem is setting up a camera in the game engine.
I wanted 4 camera views instead of one.
Front, Back, eyes view and side view; Something like minecraft game.
It will be very helpful if you can give me a tutorial of it.
Please include how to change camera view; for example, pressing f1 = front view , f2 = eyes view.

When I try to set my camera on eyes view I want the camera to see my hand when I walk or run, but the character body is blocking the view. Is there anyway to solve this or make the camera look through the body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rotate the camera by 90 degree steps when you want to change the view. To avoid that the body blocks the view simply parent the camera to your character at the eye's, like this:

[image]

In the camera settings adjust the *Focal Length*
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your question covers a lot of ground.
For starters, I recommend you set up **4** separate cameras. This is easier than having your camera move to the different desired positions.

switching between cameras requires a spot of code (at least the way I've done it.)
however if you wish to display your separate views simultaneously, a tutorial to check into is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-TtTBGSOii4.

as far as seeing through your own head: make sure your render settings are set to 'Blender Game' and turn to the material properties of your object. Click the check mark next to Backface culling. This should allow you to view the world though your own head.[image: See this image for reference.]